# error 1005 (hy000) can't create table (errno 150) in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

[image: mysql problem screenshot]

As in screenshot, both the fields: cust_id in customer table and Store_ID in ShelfLocation table have the same signature, still I am not able to reference cust_id from Store_ID.
Any help?

Comment: Try giving your foreign key a unique name

Comment: Does the table `ShelfLocation` already contain rows when you try to add the key?  If it does and any of row has a `Store_ID` which does not match `customer.cust_id`, you'll get errors (though I cannot remember for certain if that causes err150)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: No, table ShelfLocation is empty, still I am not able to refer.

Comment: @Laurence: what unique name?? as in how??

Comment: @VivekSethi `Alter Table ShelfLocation Add Constraint FK_GiveLozABeer Foreign Key (Store_ID) References Customer (cust_id);`

Comment: @Laurence: Tried the query you specified, but I am getting the same error:
"ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'bankDB.#sql-469_46' (errno: 150)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved it for me:
Add before first line:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

Add after last line:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is checking to make sure `Primary_Key` and `Foreign_Key` exactly match their data types.

If one is signed and the other is unsigned, it will fail.
Good practice is to make sure both are unsigned INT.